# The cycle continues - VM's part 4

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xaml

So, this is my refactored VM:

```cs
public partial class MainPageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IThemeProvider _ThemeProvider;
    private IStartupVersionProvider _StartupVersionProvider;
    private IFontSizeProvider _FontSizeProvider;

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Back { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Forward { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList { get; set; }
    public bool NavButtonUsed { get; set; }

    private MenuItem _currentItem = new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("OneNote"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.WSOneNote);
    public MenuItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_currentItem)) { return; }
            _currentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _searchList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> SearchList
    {
        get { return _searchList; }
        set
        {
            if (_searchList == value) return;
            _searchList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _theme = 0;
    public int Theme
    {
        get { return _theme; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _theme) return;
            _theme = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _fontSize = 20;
    public int SetFontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _fontSize) return;
            _fontSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private OneNoteVersionEnum _startupVersion = OneNoteVersionEnum.WStore;
    public OneNoteVersionEnum StartupVersion
    {
        get { return _startupVersion; }
        set
        {
            if (_startupVersion == value) return;
            _startupVersion = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private OneNoteVersionEnum _OneNoteVersion = OneNoteVersionEnum.WStore;
    public OneNoteVersionEnum OneNoteVersion
    {
        get { return _OneNoteVersion; }
        set
        {
            if (_OneNoteVersion == value) return;
            _OneNoteVersion = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public static ResourceLoader resourceFile = new ResourceLoader();

    public MainPageVM(IThemeProvider themeProvider, IStartupVersionProvider startupVersionProvider, IFontSizeProvider fontSizeProvider)
    {
        _ThemeProvider = themeProvider;
        _StartupVersionProvider = startupVersionProvider;
        _FontSizeProvider = fontSizeProvider;

        Theme = _ThemeProvider.GetCurrentTheme();
        SetFontSize = _FontSizeProvider.GetCurrentFontSize();
        StartupVersion = (OneNoteVersionEnum)_StartupVersionProvider.GetCurrentStartupVersion();

        Back = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        Forward = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        NavButtonUsed = false;

        OneNoteVersion = StartupVersion;
        SwitchTutorial(OneNoteVersion);

        CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
    }

    public void InsertItemListItem(int index, string title, Type page, Menus menu)
    {
        ItemList.Insert(index, new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString(title), page, menu));
    }

    public void SelectionChangedWS()
    {
        if (!NavButtonUsed) { Back.Insert(0, CurrentItem); }

        if (Forward.Count != 0 && !NavButtonUsed) { Forward.Clear(); }

        if (CurrentItem.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { return; }

        // Remove menu items to close menu - title starts with space
        ItemList.RemoveAll(item => item.Title.StartsWith(" "));

        switch (CurrentItem.Menu)
        {
            // I insert these at 1 because 0 is the index of the menu, and I inserted them backwards so I could insert them all in the same index to better represent they are all part of the same menu.
            case Menus.WSOneNote:
                InsertItemListItem(1, "WSNotes", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Notes), Menus.WSOneNote);
                InsertItemListItem(1, "WSPages", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Pages), Menus.WSOneNote);
                InsertItemListItem(1, "WSSections", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Section), Menus.WSOneNote);
                InsertItemListItem(1, "WSNotebooks", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Notebook), Menus.WSOneNote);
                break;

            case Menus.WSMainMenu:
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSDraw", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Draw), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSUndo", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Undo), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSTag", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Tag), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSPaste", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Paste), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSList", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.List), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSTable", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Table), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSInsertFile", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.FileInsert), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                InsertItemListItem(2, "WSPicture", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Submenus.Picture), Menus.WSMainMenu);
                break;

            /* ... */

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SelectionChanged2013()
    {
        if (!NavButtonUsed) { Back.Insert(0, CurrentItem); }

        if (Forward.Count != 0 && !NavButtonUsed) { Forward.Clear(); }

        if (CurrentItem.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { return; }

        // Remove menu items to close menu - title starts with space
        ItemList.RemoveAll(item => item.Title.StartsWith(" "));

        switch (CurrentItem.Menu)
        {
            /* Same things as above */
        }
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        NavButtonUsed = true;

        Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
        Back.RemoveAt(0);

        if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu)
        {
            CurrentItem = ItemList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Menu == Back[0].Menu);
        }

        CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
        NavButtonUsed = false;
    }

    public void GoForward()
    {
        NavButtonUsed = true;
        CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Forward[0])];
        Back.Insert(0, Forward[0]);
        Forward.RemoveAt(0);
        NavButtonUsed = false;
    }

    public void SwitchTutorial(OneNoteVersionEnum version)
    {
        if (ItemList.Count != 0) { CurrentItem = ItemList[0]; }
        ItemList.RemoveAll(item => item.Title != resourceFile.GetString("OneNote"));

        Back.Clear();
        Forward.Clear();

        if (version == OneNoteVersionEnum.WStore)
        {
            OneNoteVersion = OneNoteVersionEnum.WStore;

            InsertItemListItem(0, "OneNote", typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.WSOneNote);
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSMainMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.MainMenu), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTextMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.TextMenu), Menus.WSTextMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTextBlockMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.TextBlockMenu), Menus.WSTextBlockMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTableMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.TableMenu), Menus.WSTableMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTableCellsMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.TableCellsMenu), Menus.WSTableCellsMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSDrawMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.DrawMenu), Menus.WSDrawMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSDrawnItemsMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.DrawnItemsMenu), Menus.WSDrawnItemsMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSPictureMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.PictureMenu), Menus.WSPictureMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSFileMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.File), Menus.WSFileMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSAppBarsMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.AppBar), Menus.WSAppBarsMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSCharmsMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.Charms), Menus.WSCharmsMenu));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSKeyboardShortcutsMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.KeyboardShortcuts), Menus.WSKeyboardShortcuts));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSColorPalateMenu"), typeof(Tutorials.WindowsData.ColorPalate), Menus.WSColorPalate));

            CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
            if (ItemList[5].Title == resourceFile.GetString("OneNote")) { ItemList.RemoveAt(5); }
        }

        if (version == OneNoteVersionEnum.WPhone)
        {
            OneNoteVersion = OneNoteVersionEnum.WPhone;

            InsertItemListItem(0, "OneNote", typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.OneNote), Menus.WPOneNote);
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPNotebooks"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Notebook), Menus.WPOneNote));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPSections"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Sections), Menus.WPOneNote));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPPages"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Pages), Menus.WPOneNote));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPNotes"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Notes), Menus.WPOneNote));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPCortana"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Cortana), Menus.WPOneNote));

            CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
            if (ItemList[1].Title == resourceFile.GetString("OneNote")) { ItemList.RemoveAt(1); }
        }

        if (version == OneNoteVersionEnum.Desktop2013)
        {
            OneNoteVersion = OneNoteVersionEnum.Desktop2013;

            InsertItemListItem(0, "OneNote", typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.OneNote), Menus.OneNote2013);
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("File2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.FileTab), Menus.File2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Home2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.HomeTab), Menus.Home2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Insert2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.InsertTab), Menus.Insert2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Draw2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.DrawTab), Menus.Draw2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("History2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.HistoryTab), Menus.History2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Review2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.ReviewTab), Menus.Review2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("View2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.ViewTab), Menus.View2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Playback2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.PlaybackTab), Menus.Playback2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Layout2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.LayoutTab), Menus.Layout2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Design2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.DesignTab), Menus.Design2013));
            ItemList.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Share2013"), typeof(Tutorials.Desktop2013Data.Menus.ShareTab), Menus.Share2013));

            CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
            if (ItemList[1].Title == resourceFile.GetString("OneNote")) { ItemList.RemoveAt(1); }
        }

        OneNoteVersion = version;
    }

    public void SearchAndSort(ref string[] query)
    {
        List<int> weight = new List<int>();

        int position = -1;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string[], MenuItem> val in SearchKeys.SearchData)
        {
            position++;
            int length = val.Key.Length;
            int middle = length / 2;
            char firstCharMidArray = val.Key[middle][0];

            foreach (string s in query)
            {
                if (s.Length == 0) continue;

                int min = val.Key[middle][0] < s[0] ? middle : 0;
                int max = val.Key[middle][0] <= s[0] ? val.Key.Length : middle + 1;

                for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
                {
                    weight.Add(0);

                    if (val.Key[i] == s)
                    {
                        if (weight[position] == 0)
                        {
                            SearchList.Add(val.Value);
                        }
                        weight[position]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        SortResults(ref weight);
    }

    private void SortResults(ref List<int> weights)
    {
        while (weights.Contains(0)) weights.Remove(0);

        ObservableCollection<MenuItem> localValues = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        List<int> localWeights = new List<int>();

        int index = -1;
        var weightsWithIndex = weights.Select(p => new { Value = p, Index = ++index }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);

        foreach (var w in weightsWithIndex)
        {
            localWeights.Add(w.Value);
            localValues.Add(SearchList[w.Index]);
        }

        SearchList = localValues;
        weights = localWeights;
    }
}
```

This is some of the supporting material used by the VM:

```cs
public enum OneNoteVersionEnum
{
    WStore, WPhone, Desktop2013
}

public enum Menus
{
    WSOneNote, WSMainMenu, WSTextMenu, WSTextBlockMenu, WSTableMenu, WSTableCellsMenu,
    WSDrawMenu, WSDrawnItemsMenu, WSPictureMenu, WSFileMenu, WSAppBarsMenu, WSCharmsMenu,
    WSKeyboardShortcuts, WSColorPalate,

    WPOneNote,

    OneNote2013, File2013, Home2013, Insert2013, Draw2013, History2013, Review2013, View2013,
    Playback2013, Layout2013, Design2013, Share2013,

    SearchResult
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string title, Type page, Menus menu)
    {
        Title = title;
        Page = page;
        Menu = menu;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)obj;
        return menu.Title == Title && menu.Page == Page && menu.Menu == Menu;
    }

    private string _title = "";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    private Type _page = null;
    public Type Page
    {
        get { return _page; }
        set { _page = value; }
    }

    private Menus _menu = new Menus();
    public Menus Menu
    {
        get { return _menu; }
        set { _menu = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is a quick example of how it is used:

```xml
<AppBar Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="StoreOneNote" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource ABButton}" Content="Windows&#10;Store" Click="Store_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="PhoneOneNote" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource ABButton}" Content="Windows&#10;Phone" Click="Phone_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="OneNote2013Button" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource ABButton}" Content="OneNote 2013" Click="OneNote2013_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
</AppBar>

<AppBar Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,10,0">
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="Back_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding Back.Count, Converter={StaticResource BackToBool}}"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" Click="Forward_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding Forward.Count, Converter={StaticResource ForwardToBool}}"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</AppBar>
```

```cs
private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data.GoBack();
}

private void Forward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data.GoForward();
}

private void Store_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data.SwitchTutorial(OneNoteVersionEnum.WStore);
}

private void Phone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data.SwitchTutorial(OneNoteVersionEnum.WPhone);
}

private void OneNote2013_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data.SwitchTutorial(OneNoteVersionEnum.Desktop2013);
}
```

If you need any more information, please let me know.  I removed some very repetitive code to shorten my question so it would fit better and be more easily reviewable, but the gist of it is the same.  What I am mainly looking for is whether I am using the MVVM model correctly, but I am sure there are things that can be improved as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I don't like about your design is, that you are creating and removing `MenuItems` all the time.

You should consider to create a new class `MenuItemManager` which is loading all the `MenuItem`'s at the start and then providing properties or methods to retrieve the loaded `MenuItem`'s.

You should consider to change the `OneNoteVersionEnum` enum to `AppVersion` or `ApplicationVersion` to keep the possibility of extending your application to take care of other applications too.

**MenuItem**

Calling `Equals()` with an object which isn't a `MenuItem` will result in an `InvalidCastException`.

If `Equals()` is overridden it is mandatory (at least if you use a `Dictionary` or `HashMap`) or at least recommended to override `GetHashCode()` too.

You should add a property for holding the mentioned `AppVersion` for filtering. Using auto properties with public getters and private setters will reduce the amount of code.

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public Type Page { get; private set; }
    public Menus Menu { get; private set; }
    public AppVersion Version { get; private set; }

    public MenuItem(string title, Type page, Menus menu, AppVersion appVersion)
    {
        Title = title;
        Page = page;
        Menu = menu;
        Version = appVersion;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MenuItem test = (MenuItem)obj;

        MenuItem other = obj as MenuItem;
        if (other == null) { return false; }

        return other.Title == this.Title &&
               other.Page == this.Page &&
               other.Menu == this.Menu &&
               other.Version == this.Version;

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = 13;
            hash = (hash * 7) ^ this.Title.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) ^ this.Page.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) ^ this.Menu.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) ^ this.Version.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
public enum AppVersion
{
    OneNoteWStore, OneNoteWPhone, Desktop2013
}
```

To manage your `MenuItem`'s, we add a `MenuItemManager` class which contains methods to fill and retrieve the items

```
public class MenuItemManager
{
    private List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

    public MenuItem this[String title]
    {
        get
        {
            return menuItems.Find(m => m.Title == title);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetMenuItems(AppVersion version)
    {
        return menuItems.Where(m => m.Version == version);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetMenuItems(Menus menu)
    {
        return menuItems.Where(m => m.Menu == menu);
    }

    public MenuItemManager()
    {
        Fill();
    }

    private void Fill()
    {
        //use this to fill the meniItems  
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WPCortana"), typeof(Tutorials.PhoneData.Submenus.Cortana), Menus.WPOneNote));

        //...
    }
}
```

which can be extended to retrieve `MenuItem`(s) based on different criteria.

So e.g the former `SelectionChangedWS()` method could be simplified to

```
MenuItemManager manager = new MenuItemManager();
public void SelectionChangedWS()
{
    if (!NavButtonUsed) { Back.Insert(0, CurrentItem); }

    if (Forward.Count != 0 && !NavButtonUsed) { Forward.Clear(); }

    if (CurrentItem.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { return; }

    // Remove menu items to close menu - title starts with space
    ItemList.RemoveAll(item => item.Title.StartsWith(" "));

    foreach (MenuItem item in manager.GetMenuItems(CurrentItem.Menu))
    {
        ItemList.Insert(1, item);
    }

}
```

which leads to the possibility to combine `SelectionChanged2013()` and `SelectionChangedWS()` into one method.

Comment: Great points - especially about the `MenuItemManager` - I really hated that, and wasn't sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get some of this cleared out of the way, I realized I can change `MenuItem` to this simpler version:

```cs
public string Title
{
    get;
    set;
}

public Type Page
{
    get;
    set;
}

public Menus Menu
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Also, I should merge `SelectionChangedWS` and `SelectionChanged2013` as they are doing the same thing, although it will become a monster method that way.  If I really want to keep them separate, I should at least merge them and only put the `switch` statements in their own methods.